# Analytics JS AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am writing some js code to send user-page interaction data to analytics server. I am in this context:

1. No Google analytics.
2. No third party library.

And I need to achieve:

1. shouldn't block user navigation. (or as invisible as possible)
2. should ensure each request is sent to the server.
3. should be universal, not servlet solution for one site.

Currently what I observed from making a normal AJAX request is when I navigate to another page, the request is canceled from browser side, which indicated data loss.

Any comment/answer is welcome.

Comment: make the ajax request from the new page, on page load?

Comment: If you code the analytics yourself, then why do you use js+ajax at all for this? Just incorportate the functionality in the server that receives the requests anyway. You won't get any problems from that.

Comment: @levi how do I pass the ajax request down to the new page?

Comment: @Bergi good question ... but we are not only building the analytics for our own website ...

Comment: Maybe you want to look into what other analytic services are doing? Instead if an ajax request, they are dynamically inserting an image in the page that contains the necessary info. Inserting the image hits their server, and that's how they track the events.

Comment: @Robin it makes sense. But we are building features like time spent, button click ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of this is possible, isn't it? Because google definitely tracks all of that. Button click, easy, just insert an image per click with the info, for time spent, not sure. Your script can track the time spent on the page, and then insert the image just before the page changes (track url change, not sure how else to do that).

Comment: @Robin, Currently we will do the image way only when javascript is disabled. Will insert image trigger the browser to load for sure?

Comment: Hum, but you have to have javascript to request the image. They do something like `var img = new Image(); img.src="http://google-analytics/__utm.gif?additional_params=xyz`. A bit more info: http://groups.google.com/group/analytics-help-basics/msg/815c0138973292d4

Comment: @Robin One problem I am facing is "Navigation (another page loading) will cancel ongoing AJAX call". Will this image approach ensure "hitting the server" and "won't block user navigation"?

Comment: Yep, definitely, that's one of the reasons they use this method. As soon as the img object is created by the script, the browser will request the image, and so your server will be hit (and you'll also receive the additional_params sent).